# In vscode how to check if a c++ method is private or public in editor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In vscode how to check if a method is private, public or protected in editor?
If there is a solution to show this in outline that will help too.

EDIT: I can check the header file to see access level, but I want to see it in cc file in popup or in outline.

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? Can't you look if it's in a `private:`, `public:`, or `protected:` section?

Comment: Well C++ has sections, private, public and protected, below that section is anything with that access. It doesnt matter if its vscode, visual studio od code::blocks

Comment: do you mean you are in the source file looking at definitions and want to know a methods access level? Go to the header

Answer (score 0):

C++ access is defined by sections.
A class example

```cpp
class Example{
    public: 
        //anything that is public goes here
    protected:
        //anything protected goes here
    private:
        //anything private goes here
};
```

The default access is private.
You do not need to write all of these sections, nor in this order but it is generally good to write it like this `public, protected, private`.

It doesn't matter if you are in vscode, visual studio or code::blocks, the editor itself doesn't affect the code.

To access methods and fields from class you have 3 options

- Public members can be access everywhere
- Protected members act like private for every other scenario except for inherited classes. The classes that inherit base class can access protected fields and methods.
- Private members of the class can only be accessed by that class itself.